# Can cracks in a wood-burning fireplace be repaired with a concrete product?

Tags: concrete, fireplace, brick

Upon inspection, minor cracks were found on the floor & back of wood burning fireplace.  Can't these cracks be filled with some type of concrete repair kit?  If so, what is recommended for the heat?  It is a grouted brick in grey.

Comment: I think you first need to decide if repair is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Refractory cement is usually used to repair the the joints of the fire brick. If the old cement is cracking it may be a good idea to remove all the loose material and repoint or fill the damaged areas. There is also fire clay but this not normally used above the fire box area that takes the most abuse from the fire (I have seen fire clay used many times but believe refractory cement is better).